# docbook (openjade) <title> ignored by <xref>, produces "Chapter 33", "Section 33.2" etc

Tags: xslt, docbook

*TL;DR: In my docbook SGML, when converted to HTML by openjade using docbook-dsssl stylesheets, `xref` elements produce linktext like "Chapter 33" instead of "The title of the chapter" from the `<chapter>`'s `<title>` element. I want it to emit the title and can't figure out how to make it.*

---

I'm struggling with docbook linktext even after reading [the introductory/newbie docs](http://newbiedoc.sourceforge.net/metadoc/docbook-guide.html#LINKS-DOCBOOK-GUIDE), [tech docs](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/CrossRefs.html), [customisation docs](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/CustomXrefs.html) and [`xref` element docs](http://docbook.org/tdg/en/html/xref.html).

Unless I use an explicit `<link linkend="blah">text</link>` I'm always getting linktext for `xref` like *Chapter 33* or *Section 33.2.1*, with no title.

e.g. if I have:

```
<chapter id="spi">
  <title>Server Programming Interface</title>
```

and reference it with:

```
<xref linkend="spi">
```

I get linktext like *Chapter 33* instead of the expected *Chapter 33: Server Programming Interface* or just *Server Programming Interface*.

The stylesheets used don't specify `xref.with.number.and.title`. If I explicitly add:

```
<xsl:param name="xref.with.number.and.title">1</xsl:param>
```

to the `stylesheet.xsl` it doesn't change the output I see.

I can't find any `<l:context` / `<l:template` gentext customisation in [`stylesheet-common.xsl`](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=doc/src/sgml/stylesheet-common.xsl) or [`stylesheet.xsl`](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=doc/src/sgml/stylesheet.xsl) (there's some in `stylesheet-man.xsl` but it's not used for building the HTML docs, only the manpages, and the overridden templates don't produce the text I see).

I can override the linktext with an `xreflabel` attribute on the target element, but that's clumsy when there's already a `<title>` there. Similarly I can give the `<title>` an `id` and reference it from the `xref` element, but it's clumsy and not supposed to be necessary.

**I'm stumped. Why would `<xref>` linktext ignore the `<title>` element?**

---

Context: I'm working on [the PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/) which is [written in DocBook SGML](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/docguide-docbook.html) and uses [openjade and the DocBook 4.2 DTD](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/docguide-toolsets.html), using OpenJade 1.3.2 (OpenSP 1.5.2) with docbook-dsssl 1.79.

The relevant stylesheets are in public git [`doc/src/sgml`](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=tree;f=doc/src/sgml).

When built the `openjade` command line is:

```
openjade  -wall -wno-unused-param -wno-empty -wfully-tagged \
    -D . -D . -c /usr/share/sgml/docbook/dsssl-stylesheets/catalog \
    -d stylesheet.dsl -t sgml -i output-html -i include-index \
    postgres.sgml
```

---

There's the following in [`stylesheet.dsl`](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=doc/src/sgml/stylesheet.dsl):

```
;; Avoid excessive cross-reference labels
(define (auto-xref-indirect? target ancestor)
  (cond
;   ;; Always add indirect references to another book
;   ((member (gi ancestor) (book-element-list))
;    #t)
   ;; Add indirect references to the section or component a block
   ;; is in iff chapters aren't autolabelled.  (Otherwise "Figure 1-3"
   ;; is sufficient)
   ((and (member (gi target) (block-element-list))
         (not %chapter-autolabel%))
    #t)
   ;; Add indirect references to the component a section is in if
   ;; the sections are not autolabelled
   ((and (member (gi target) (section-element-list))
         (member (gi ancestor) (component-element-list))
         (not %section-autolabel%))
    #t)
   (else #f)))
```

but removing it has no effect.

Comment: If you are using the SGML version of DocBook and the DocBook DSSSL stylesheets, then the "xslt" tag is misleading. It seems like most of the the text between the first and second horizontal lines does not belong here, since it is about DocBook XSL (a completely different toolchain).

Comment: @mzjn OK. That's mighty confusing, then. The source tree contains a bunch of `.sgml` files with the masters of the documentation, plus some `stylesheet-[medium].xsl` files like `stylesheet-man.xsl` and a `stylesheet.dsl`. It *appears* to be using the DocBook DSSSL stylesheets and fails if they're absent from the system, but *also* appears to be using XSLT. That does not make the situation much more enlightening :S